# Why is libtool is throwing "unsupported hardcode properties" errors and what do they mean?

Tags: cross-compiling, gettext, libtool, hardcode

I am cross-compiling [`gettext-0.18.2`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) for Windows but running into some problems. During the linking stages of one of the shared libraries, `libtool` gives me the following error message:

```
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX ...
libtool: link: unsupported hardcode properties
libtool: link: See the libtool documentation for more information.
libtool: link: Fatal configuration error.
```

You can see the full build log including the `libtool` command [here](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/112732258/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-i386.gettext_0.18.2-0~201208141836~precise1_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz) (the error is at the very bottom of the page).

What would cause this error and what does it mean? I can't seem to find any information about this error in the documentation, despite the claim in the error message.

Also of note: the thing that really makes this weird is that [the build succeeded without error on Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal)](https://code.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/win-cross/+build/3724191/+files/buildlog_ubuntu-quantal-i386.gettext_0.18.2-0%7E201208141838%7Equantal1_BUILDING.txt.gz)... but it's failing on Ubuntu 12.04, the current LTS release.

---

**Additional:** I did a diff of the line invoking `libtool` between the build that succeeded and the build that failed. The diff looks something like this:

[image]

So apparently the C++ compiler is being omitted from the command. Could this cause the above error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Aha!

The problem turned out to be extremely subtle. The [mingw-w64 [image: Install mingw-w64]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mingw-w64) package in Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal) lists [g++-mingw-w64 [image: Install g++-mingw-w64]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/g++-mingw-w64) as a dependency - but this is not the case in Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise). So all I needed to do was to specify `g++-mingw-w64` as a build dependency.

The reason for the actual error message above was because the configure script couldn't find the C++ compiler for the cross-compiler toolchain:

Quantal:

```
checking for g++... i686-w64-mingw32-g++
checking whether the C++ compiler (...) works... yes
```

Precise:

```
checking for g++... i686-w64-mingw32-g++
checking whether the C++ compiler (...) works... no
```

Comment: I had a very different issue - actually this: http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/ticket/362 - with the same symptoms. I was not cross-compiling. My solution was very related to the tricky way my machine is configured, so I'll spare people the details, but the bottom line is that there was an issue with how the g++ compiler interacted with libtools and your answer put me on the right track.

Comment: I think you found a bug in the MinGW packaging.  Good job, and I would recommend that you report it to the MinGW package maintainer so that they can fix it.

Comment: @InkBlend: I doubt that it is a bug - it's very possible that someone would need the C compiler and not the C++ compiler. And besides, as of Quantal (12.10) and onward, `g++` is now installed by default with the toolchain.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison, that was stupid of me.  I was looking for a solution to my problem, found yours instead, and got them mixed up.  You are right, it is definitely _not_ a bug.  I apologize.

Comment: @InkBlend: Don't worry - no harm done. I hope you find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know it can be trivial, but be sure to have libtool-dev installed, too:

```
sudo apt-get install libtool
sudo apt-get install libtool-dev
```